# Exception when resolving CustomPluginFactory in ModuleLifecycle

Tags: c#, moryx

I have a custom Module with the following code in the `ModuleController`

```cs
[ServerModule(ModuleName)]
public class ModuleController : ServerModuleBase<ModuleConfig> 
{
    private ICustomComponent _customComponent
    ...
    protected override void OnStart()
    {
        _customComponent = Container.Resolve<ICustomComponentFactory>().Create(Config.CustomComponentConfig);
        ...
    }
}
```

The interface for the factory is defined as follows

```cs
[PluginFactory(typeof(IConfigBasedComponentSelector))]
internal interface ICustomComponentFactory
{
    ICustomComponent Create(CustomComponentConfig config);

    void Destroy(ICustomComponent connector);
}
```

When I start the module, it crashes at the resolve statement and I get a *Castle.DynamicProxy.Generators.GeneratorException*

Comment: Could you add some more details about the exception?